# Добавляем спецсимвол в HTML.

Tags: phonegap, мобильные-приложения, android, html, символы

Сделал страницу. И нужно вставит символ ☣ (биологическая опасность) но когда создаю файл apk он не отображается (символ) (я делаю приложение)

Comment: куда и как вставляете? 

просто один и тот же символ можно вставить тремя способами

&[name];

&#[id];

и через комбинацию клавиш (вроде как Alt+числа) при врубленном нумлоке)

Comment: я посмотрел эту страницу с андроидовского браузера - там этот символ не отображается. Также он в приложении gmail не отображается. Так что я думаю, это проблема в том, что этого символа просто нет в стандартном шрифте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указывайте символ как utf `U+2623` или как html code `&#9763;`